# Android When double click button to start another activity, app is closed without crash

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-button, android-dialog

My application consists of 2 activities.

1. MainActivity
2. TestActivity

In MainActivity there is a button and when click the button, TestActivity is started.
App's theme is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
And set window size with this code.

```
window.apply{
            attributes.apply {
                width = 800
                height = 800
            }
            clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
            setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        }
```

The thing is, when I click the button many times very quickly,
then my application is closed without any error.

When I come back to the app through recents app, I can see the TestActivity opened.
And when I enter the app through recents app, then button works okay.
Also, set the app theme to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" then it works okay too.

So I tried to avoid double click in several ways, but nothing was different.
One of my codes is like this.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("TAG", "button clicked")
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            startActivity(Intent(this, TestActivity::class.java))
        }
```

Is there any problem in "Theme.Appcompat.Dialog" ?

MainActivity's lifecycle stops at onStop(), not onDestroy().
And right before the onStop() is called, I can see the log.

**W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7527b63010 disconnect failed**

- It only happens at my device(Android 8.0). Another device(android 10.0) was ok.
- if `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` is added to style.xml, than it happens. After I remove this one, it works ok.

Comment: why not use a dialogFragment instead an activity?

Comment: Why do you need your first activity to be a floating view? But anyway, after the first click you can always disable click events on the button like this: button.setClickable(false).

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem I need an activity, not a fragment, that looks like floating view, so I used activity with appcompat.dialog theme. And this is the first activity of my app.

Comment: @SlothCoding I'm just following the design guideline so I have to do this that way.. And I also have done it before to set clickable fasle, but it doesn't work when I click it so fast. So I tried to use thread.sleep(500), but it just block click for just a moment and app is closed.

Comment: Can you try to put your code in try { } catch { } and catch the stack trace when the crash happens? Do that for every piece of code you write. Check logs for any exceptions and paste them here. There must be something in the background that's causing this.

Comment: @SlothCoding Nothing happened...But when I printed log, here is the log. D/TAG: button clicked
D/TAG: Main :: onPause()
D/TAG: Test :: onCreate()
D/TAG: Test :: onResume()
D/TAG: Test :: onPause()
D/TAG: Main :: onStop()
D/TAG: Test :: onStop()
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e8bb73010 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7e8bed6c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7e8bb0c680

Comment: @SlothCoding And also, I found that this occurs only at my test device that has the version of Android 8.0.. When I tested on another device, android version 10, it works ok. And if <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> is added in style file, then the error happens.

Comment: Did you set your activity orientation to portrait by any chance? As much as I can see that happens on Oreo. Mixing windowIsTranslucent and screenOrientation:portrait gives this crash on Oreo.

Comment: @SlothCoding No.. I didn't set the orientation.. And my app never crash, it is just closed without crash.